# How do I display a timechart with more than one custom metric in Azure Logs with Kusto Query Language

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, azureportal, kql

I have the following Logs in Azure Logs:

[image]

The query for the above is as follows:

[image]

The output is shown below appearing like a 'scatter diagram' but I am looking for a timechart - like connecting the dots but failed to do so:

[image]

How do I join the dots or is there a limitation or the way the KQL above (Kusto Query Language) is written?

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Comment: Hi @BhargaviAnnadevara, yep, had a solution. I did a summarize by:

summarize by bin(timestamp, 1m), monitorTotalScanTime, monitorContainerScanTime, monitorInventoryScanTime, monitorClassificationScanTime, monitorRCScanTime
render timechart;

so, the bin(timestamp, 1m) is the first parameter.

Comment: Glad you have it working now. Please consider [upvoting and accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you found it helpful so it helps others in the community with similar queries. :)

Answer (score 3):

It is your KQL query that has to be modified. The key to getting your time-series charts right is to fetch all the time and metric information in the result set from your query.

Remember that when constructing a timechart, the first column is the x-axis, and should be datetime. Other (numeric) columns are y-axes. There is one string column whose values are used to "group" the numeric columns and create different lines in the chart (further string columns are ignored).

Considering the `requests` table as an example (you can apply it to your `customEvents` data as appropriate), multiple metrics can be plotted as:

```
# Time-series chart with multiple metrics
requests
| summarize Requests = count(), Users = dcount(user_Id) by bin(timestamp, 1h)
| render timechart
```

Output:
[image: Plot multiple metrics]

The query control uses timestamp for the X-axis and Requests & Users as separate series on the Y-axis here.